# How to get same effect as jQuery's slideToggle using CSS 3 transitions?

Tags: jquery, mobile, css

I want the jQuery slideToggle effect but want to use CSS3 transitions in order to invoke the GPU on an iOS device so the transition is smoother.

Comment: I don't do iOS dev, so I can't test it, but what about move.js or animatable?  Rather than toggle, just have an if/else statment to which which position the element is in.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can achieve this by transitioning `height`, `padding`'s and `border-width`. Here is an example:

```js
$('.run-css').click(function() {
    $('.cont').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

```css
.cont {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px #CCC solid;
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s linear, padding-top .3s linear, padding-bottom .3s linear, border-top-width .3s linear, border-top-width .3s linear;
    transition: height .3s linear, padding-top .3s linear, padding-bottom .3s linear, border-top-width .3s linear, border-top-width .3s linear;
}
.toggled {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="run-css">CSS slideToggle</button>

<div class="cont">Toggle this div</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is. Pure CSS means that effect itself does not require JavaScript. I used JS for demo purposes to toggle class that triggers effect.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry but this is not supported by CSS3 unless you know the exact height. There is no way to animate between 0 and auto. If you do know the exact height, you can generate some transition codes here: http://css3generator.com/

Comment: That is the thing I am keep on looking for the solution without mentioning `height`

Answer (score 6):

True, you cannot animate between 0 and auto height, but you can actually toggle the max-height.

Toggle (via JS) between `max-height:0` and `max-height:1000px` and you'll get the achieved result, though it won't be quite as smooth as jQuery's slideToggle function.

Couple it with an opacity fade and it looks pretty good. I strongly suggest only using this technique on relatively short containers though, as the large ones can create a jerky animation.

Comment: Interesting. I played with this and it's not the size of the container that makes it jerky... it's the difference between the `max-height` and the actual content height. Thus, you might as well need to know the content height, if you want to prevent a jerky experience (and if you know the content height, you can just transition over `height`).

Answer (score 5):

```
.container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 0;

    transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
.container.open {
    max-height: 1000px; /* approx */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Animatable](http://lea.verou.me/2011/10/animatable-a-css-transitions-gallery/) should do the trick.  It's a CSS Transitions framework, and although I don't do iOS development, Lea Verou mentions that she test it on FF and Chrome for iOS.

There's other CSS animation libraries, like [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/) that use CSS transitions and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for this is by using transform: scale3D and transform-origin. It is not perfect but still better than nothing. It has to be combined with show/hide.

```
.slideIn {
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.slideOut {
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}


@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(1, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```