# Collapse effect toggle

Tags: jquery, css

I have a little toggle script for navbar. How can I add a animate effect?

This is the script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".collapse").toggleClass(".collapse in");
    });
});
```

And this is the CSS

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Just use `toggle("slow")` http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: but where i can put toggle slow. I know the function but where

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".collapse").toggle("slow");
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `opacity` of the element with this CSS:

```
.collapse {
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.collapse.in {
    opacity:1;
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tchv5vwe/)

Answer (score 0):

You can [improve your CSS with elaborated css3 transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860631/how-to-get-same-effect-as-jquerys-slidetoggle-using-css-3-transitions) or you can use jQuery [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".collapse").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwaf2ru5/1/).