# whats "wrong" with this toggle script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I use this JS-code to toggle out my responsive menu but it don't work out smooth in phones. Can you see why?

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('.slide-toggle');
            menu        = $('.menu');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle(500);
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 768 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!0

Comment: Using jquery animation e.g : `slideToggle` is often slow on mobile, you can try to look up css3 transition instead (see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860631/how-to-get-same-effect-as-jquerys-slidetoggle-using-css-3-transitions)

Comment: +1 for CSS3 transition suggestion. The `slideToggle` requires a JS function to fire every few ms via `setTimeout`. Since JS is slower and there is no guarantee of consistent firing - especially on mobile - you will get significant jittering. CSS3 transitions are implemented in native code and almost always appear smooth.

Comment: Thank u a lot! I will look up CSS3 transition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a CSS3 animation that will help you along the way for implementing a sliding menu. I was unsure of exactly how you menu would behave, but I think this will give you a good starting point. https://jsfiddle.net/jtholla2/73a7czm9/1/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  word-spacing: -2px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #191919;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #888;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.menu {
  background: #181818;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -250px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu h1 {
  color: #FFF;
}
#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -100%;
  top: -100%;
}
#toggle + label {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #26ae90;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
#toggle + label:after {
  content: "Open"
}
.container {
  transition: margin 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  padding: 5em 3em;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .menu {
  top: 0;
}
#toggle:checked ~ .container {
  margin-top: 250px;
}
#toggle:checked + label {
  background: #dd6149;
}
#toggle:checked + label:after {
  content: "Close"
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" />
<label for="toggle"></label>

<div class="container">
  <h1>CSS3 Slide Down Toggle Demo Menu</h1>
  <h2>Click the Open button to see the menu.</h2>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If I modify this code a little bit,  is it possible to make the menu slide in from left or right side also?