# Button onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a study  Project I try to make a sidebar for an interactive map.

I have a button which trigger an onClick() Event which Shows
a `<ul>` with an form Input.

So far I have 3 questions.

1) Can I check if the button was already clicked so I can hide my additional Content again? If so, how can I achieve that?

2) At the Moment I only display the content but I would like to have  an Animation. Again, you may give me some Infos to do this or provide an link / tutorial.

3) Is there a better Solution for my Problem, if so. May you give me a hint?

```js
function showDropdown(x) {
  let id = x;

  if (id == 1) {
    document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";
    console.log(id);
  }

  if (id == 2) {
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";
    console.log(id);
  }

  if (id == 3) {
    document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";
    console.log(id);
  } else {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-sidebar>ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <div class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <button type="button" onclick="showDropdown(1)" class="dropdown-header">Einwohner</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-item" id="1">
          <li>
            <p>Feld 1:<span style="padding-left: 10px;"><input type="text" Placeholder="a" size="2"</span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Feld 2:<span style="padding-left: 10px;"><input type="text" Placeholder="b" size="2"</span></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Feld 3:<span style="padding-left: 10px;"><input type="text" Placeholder="c" size="2"</span></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: jQuery? element.toggle or element.slideToggle

Comment: `1`, `2` and `3` are not valid `id`s. [Identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) can not start with a digit.

Comment: @UselessCode yes they can. But not in any doctype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data attribute and jQuery slidetoggle as I suggested in my comment.

Please note I do not like numeric IDs so I prefixed the ID with a u.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-header").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#" + id).slideToggle()
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-sidebar>ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <div class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <button type="button" data-id="u1" class="dropdown-header">Einwohner</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-item" id="u1">
          <li>
            <p>Feld 1:&nbsp;<input type="text" Placeholder="a" size="2" /></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Feld 2:&nbsp;<input type="text" Placeholder="b" size="2" /></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>Feld 3:&nbsp;<input type="text" Placeholder="c" size="2" /></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
The Animation has a Little Offset Close to the end. Is there a Workaround for it? 

You may aswell tell me why you disagree with Numeric ids?

Comment: They are not supported by all doctypes

Comment: if i give it a set width i will lose my responsive design on this elementent sadly.

Comment: Your html was however not valid - missing an end on the input. Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860631/how-to-get-same-effect-as-jquerys-slidetoggle-using-css-3-transitions or is that the same problem?

Comment: the -webkit solution fixed it for me, aswell Thank you very much for your effort

Answer (score 0):

You put jQuery in the tags, so I suppose you could use it, [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5may6eqd/1/)

You can use `toggle()` or `slideToggle()` function to show/hide the content.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-item').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve all of this using jQuery's `.slideToggle()` function.

```
function showDropdown(x) {
  let id = x;

  if (id == 1) {
    $("#1").slideToggle();
    console.log(id);
  }

  if (id == 2) {
     $("#2").slideToggle();
    console.log(id);
  }

  if (id == 3) {
    $("#3").slideToggle();
    console.log(id);
  } else {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```

By using slideToggle you are checking to see what the current state is, toggling it to the opposite state and it will also animate.

Edit; Another user has beat me to it.

Answer (score -1):

1- Check if button is clicked.

You can do this by assigning a variable i=0 outside, and when you perform onClick operation makeit i=1, and before you perform onclick operations, check if the value is 1 or 0.

But there is another way of doing it using jquery.

[Hide and show elements using jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

If you want to do it in little animation way. use fade function in Jquery

[Hide and show elements using fade()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)

if you want tutorial on side navigation bar

[W3schools sidenav tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp)

Comment: Please do not give link only answers and especially not poor refence sites. Instead show a good example. Cluttering the window scope with useless variables is also not a great idea